# clamping unsigned ints

Tags: c++, unsigned

What is the correct way to clamp unsigned ints?

For example, say I have:

```
 unsigned int ui = 5U;
```

Now I want to subtract a value from it:

```
ui = Clamp(ui - MAGIC_VALUE, 0, 255);
```

I would like ui to contain 0 if MAGIC_VALUE >= 5.

However, I can't just subtract MAGIC_VALUE as the expression `ui - MAGIC_VALUE` will wrap around to `UINT_MAX` if MAGIC_VALUE > 5 and end up being clamped to the upper limit, 255. That's the opposite of what I want!

Is there any trick to deal with this?

Comment: `ui = Clamp((int)ui - MAGIC_VALUE, 0, 255);` ?

Comment: `ui = (ui > MAGIC_VALUE) ? Clamp(ui - MAGIC_VALUE, 0, 255) : 0;`?